# How to set WebClient Content-Type Header?

Tags: c#, content-type, webclient

To conect to a third party service I need to make a Https Post. One of the requisites set is to sent a custom content type.

I'm using WebClient, but I can't find how to set it. I've tried making a new class and overriding the CreateRequest Method, but that make request crash.

Is there any way to do that without having to rewrite CopyHeadersTo method?

**EDIT** CopyHeaderTo is a method I've seen using .NET Reflector. It's invoked from GetWebRequest and sets all Request Headers, including Content-Type, from private properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I just missed `Request.ContentType` property. If `GetWebRequest` method is overridden, setting `ContentType` to whatever value desired does it.

Still, connection to third party is not working. Go figure.

Answer (score 47):

You could try adding to the [Headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.headers.aspx) collection.

```
myWebClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type","application/xxx");
```

Comment: That throws a WebException, saying that Content-Type cannot be changed for current petition.

Comment: Who throws this exception? Is it the server script you are posting to? I have tested the example provided in MSDN and it successfully set the Content-Type header to a custom value.

Comment: I had to do this: _client.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/Json" Still not working correctly, but at least it compiles! Working in silverlight 5.

Comment: Just wondering.. should you have called myWebClient.Headers.Remove("Content-Type") or maybe on a broader level called myWebClient.Headers.Clear() first before setting/Adding Content-Type?

Answer (score 16):

```
webclient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

Answer (score 3):

I encounter this too. And found that you must use Client Http, otherwise Browser Http will block change of Content-Type for security reason.  [This MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/1beth6ct(v=VS.95).aspx) explain that.

```
WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("http://", WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp);
WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("https://", WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp);
client.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
```