# How to add parameter to api request using WebClient.UploadString in C#

Tags: c#, json, api, post, uploadstring

I am posting a JSON request to a web api using the WebClient.UploadString method. The JSON string is created from parsing a text file into a JSON formatted string. How do I define a parameter in the request body working with my code below? It looks like I just add it to the end of my jsonPOSTString string variable?

```
string result = "";
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        result = client.UploadString(url, "POST", jsonPOSTString);
    }
```

Comment: Your JSON *is* the request body. Obviously you cannot modify it arbitrarily, it must still be JSON. Are you sure you have the correct idea of what the API expects from you?

Comment: The API expects a JSON formatted request with one parameter defined. I don't know how to add the parameter to the request body. I'm new to apis, sorry if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't telling what this code does, but I think you'll get an error from the server because you don't [supply the content-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595956/how-to-set-webclient-content-type-header):

```
string result;
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers.Add("Content-Type","application/json");
    result = client.UploadString(url, "POST", jsonPOSTString);
}
```