# C# WebClient downloading webpage source code instead of file via post request

Tags: c#, post, webclient

I am trying to make a C# app that would download and save file from the given [website](http://statistik.uni-c.dk/instregudtraek/) as csv file. However instead of downloading the correct file, it keeps saving source code of the page inside of the downloaded file. What am I doing wrong? I have tried CookiesAwareWebClient as well however it gives the same result.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();
        nvc.Add("ctl00_MainContent_InstType3ListBox_scrollTop", "0");
        nvc.Add("ctl00_MainContent_KommuneListBox_scrollTop", "0");
        nvc.Add("ctl00$MainContent$InstType3ListBox", "-1");
        nvc.Add("ctl00$MainContent$KommuneListBox", "-1");
        nvc.Add("ctl00$MainContent$UdtrękButton", "Dan+udtręk+til+CSV-format");
        byte[] result = TestPost("http://statistik.uni-c.dk/instregudtraek/", nvc);
        Debug.WriteLine("Downloading file...");
        File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\Users\\wind_spirit\\Downloads\\bar.csv", result);
    }
    private byte[] TestPost(string url, NameValueCollection nvc)
    {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        byte[] response = webClient.UploadValues(url, "POST", nvc);
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a header for csv content?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595956/how-to-set-webclient-content-type-header

Comment: @NathanS I tried it, it gives exactly the same result.